# TV show with a Lord of Buttons(?), a Raven Prince and an Android made by a Rival

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for a TV show which I watched in the 80s or early 90s. It was about a boy who somehow escaped into a magical reality where some old man (I believe he was called the Lord of Buttons, but I'm not quite sure) lives with some boys in some sort of manor house. There is also a raven who turns out to be a prince who was transformed into a raven by means of a magical cap and now can't transform back because the button of that cap is missing. I think the search for that button was an important plot element, but I could be wrong. There was also some kind of rival of the "Lord of Buttons" character, who made an android boy and introduced him into the manor house, which somehow lead to the destruction of the manor (as I recall there were a lot of blinking lights everywhere as it fell apart, and the "Lord of Buttons" character sacrificed himself to save the boys). It may have been a Czech or East German production. Anybody knows which show that would have been?

Comment: Was this a series, a "made for TV movie", or a mini-series?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a movie, not a TV series (although it might have been re-cut to series format) - loose translation of the Polish title "Akademia Pana Kleksa" would be [Mr. (Ink)Blots Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademia_pana_Kleksa_(film)), Polish/Soviet Union produced two part TV movie, based on the book [Mr. (Ink)Blots Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademia_pana_Kleksa_(novel)) by Polish author Jan Brzechwa.

[Movie summary](https://youtu.be/SLaEdEvO_TY) where the boy turned to raven (or some similar kind of bird anyway), can be seen, with the cap with button that was given to him.